# Approaches in managing data from one database to another

Tags: mysql, database

There are two databases, MAIN and TEMP, used in a website. TEMP database is used to manage data fetched from MAIN for insert/update and on publishing the data moved back to MAIN database. What can be the approaches for error handling while publishing ?

I think of below two approaches :

1. Rollback script - if error occurred while insert/update then the rollback can help.
2. Third DB Concept - Introduce a third database same as MAIN and first use this database for insert/update and if it result success then execute the same commands to MAIN database otherwise no need to update MAIN database.

I am not sure which approach is better among the two. Can there be any other approach?

Suggestions are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a transaction to move/update the data from TEMP to MAIN. You either want it to work, or not, right? Presumably leaving the state in TEMP if it doesn't?

The only case I can see where you might want to do anything different is if you deliberately want to NOT leave the data in TEMP if a publish fails (if for example there's no sensible way to follow such a case up), in which case you could consider having 2 transactions, one that removes it from TEMP followed by a second one that adds it back to MAIN only if the first succeeds, and if either of those transactions fails an error is reported and the whole thing has to be restarted again.

Using a third DB doens't help. You could still succeed with the attempt to the third DB and fail with MAIN, and keeping the third DB up to date with MAIN means you immediately double all your work.